# Twocolumn part in document

Tags: lists, environments, two-column, multicol

I'd like to stretch long lists into two or more columns. Like:

> Some single-column text.
>
> 1. Lorem  4. Sit
> 2. Ipsum  5. Amet
> 3. Dolor
>
> Another single-column text.

Or:

> Some single-column text.
>
> 1) Lorem  2) Ipsum
>   3) Dolor  4) Sit
>   5) Amet
>
> Another single-column text.

for input file containing:

```
Some single-column text.
\begin{foo}{2}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Lorem
 \item Ipsum
 \item Dolor
 \item Sit
 \item Amet 
\end{itemize}
\end{foo}
Another single-column text.
```

Thanks for any idea that can help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package provides `multicols` environment.

```
% \usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Lorem
 \item Ipsum
 \item Dolor
 \item Sit
 \item Amet 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

You may want to add a `\item[]` at the end to obtain better spacing.