# Laying out an enumerate environment evenly in two columns with a picture in between

Tags: lists, two-column, enumerate

I have a list of items inside  `enumerate`. I'd like to lay them out in two columns, separated by an image. The numbering matters, so I can't break them into two separate enumerate environment. Is there a way to persuade `multicols` to do this for me ?

An alternate strategy is to manually break, and somehow start the second enumerate at the right count. This is inelegant, but would suffice. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twocolumn part in document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/twocolumn-part-in-document)

Comment: Yes, I realized that after posting. but then an answer showed up and I can't delete it now :(. Am flagging

Comment: Since you've changed the question significantly do you still want to close it? What kind of image do you have in mind? Can you show a sample?

Comment: actually I flagged it for closing, but it isn't closed yet.

Comment: You flagged it for _deletion_ and it was deleted.  I then objected to the deletion as deleting the question also deleted my answer (not that I particularly value the answer, it's the principle that I was concerned with).  This has led to a meta question: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1341/86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \item Fourth item
  \item Fifth item
  \item Sixth item
  \item Seventh item
  \item Eighth item
  \item Ninth item
  \item Tenth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

The inelegant solution is certainly possible, and it isn't *too* inelegant as it is possible to remember where we stopped counting and resume it later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{contenum}
\newenvironment{enumeratecont}{%
  \setcounter{contenum}{\theenumi}%
  \enumerate
  \setcounter{enumi}{\thecontenum}%
}{%
  \endenumerate
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is item \arabic{enumi}
\item This is item \arabic{enumi}
\end{enumerate}
\columnbreak

Some text in between the enumeration environments
\columnbreak

\begin{enumeratecont}
\item This is item \arabic{enumi}
\item This is item \arabic{enumi}
\end{enumeratecont}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: multicol split enumerate]

Comment: The `enumitem` package has a `[resume]` key that allows you to do this automatically.  One downside of this solution is that the columns must be of equal size.